# Play change RUNNING_PID file path

Tags: scala, playframework, docker, playframework-2.0

I am trying to store the RUNNING_PID file at /var/run instead of root directory.
Tried all the options suggested at:
[Another SO question about the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351405/restarting-play-application-docker-container-results-in-this-application-is-alr)

and the solution play suggest in their documnetation: [Play additional configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration)

Yet when I start my app the RUNNING_PID file is created in root directory and the /var/run/play.pid remains empty

Comment: you will have to get more info .. Just tried the method given in play additional configuration and it works fine. I am using play 2.3.9

Comment: Does the play app have permission to write in that directory?

Comment: Yes it has all the needed permissions. I finally found the problem, fixed it as suggested in play docs: "java -Dpidfile.path=/var/run/play.pid -javaagent:newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.environment=${NEWRELIC_ENV} -jar /usr/local/webapp/my_app.jar" at first i was running it this way: "java  -javaagent:newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.environment=${NEWRELIC_ENV} -Dpidfile.path=/var/run/play.pid -jar /usr/local/webapp/my_app.jar" and this didn't work

Answer (score 4):

Put

```
play.server.pidfile.path=/var/run/RUNNING_PID
```

in your `application.conf`

Comment: It's documented in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ProductionConfiguration#Changing-the-path-of-RUNNING_PID

Answer (score 1):

Create a "play" user and group in Linux, so it runs in a secure fashion.

In the SystemD service file, and within [Service] area use:

```
[Service]

# Create the Directory /var/run/play (which Play will have write permissions to)
RuntimeDirectory=play
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0710

User=play
Group=play
```

In the ExecStart, specifically pass the system property "pidfile.path":

```
ExecStart=/opt/play-1.0.0/bin/play -Dconfig.file=/path/to/my/application.conf \
                                   -Dpidfile.path=/var/run/play/play.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

**Below worked for me in Play 2.8 ():**

Add this property to you application.conf present in conf directory:

`play.server.pidfile.path=/var/run/RUNNING_PID`

**Note:** *It will try to create a file under /var/run and if you don't want/have the right to write to the filesystem i.e you are running your application in Kubernetes (1.20) pod change it to /dev/null.*

`play.server.pidfile.path=/dev/null`

*Hope this helps, Cheers ()*.