# Play Framework cannot create RUNNING_PID File in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, playframework

I have distributed my application to a Linux (Ubuntu).  When I attempt to run the file in the bin folder from the server, I receive this error:

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/co-assist/RUNNING_PID (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.createPidFile(ProdServerStart.scala:131)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:45)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
```

I saw a few posts on this error, but nothing that fixes my issue.

I have tried creating the application.ini file and adding the play.pid file, but I am guessing that is not the fix:
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#Play-PID-Configuration

I also saw this:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration#Changing-the-path-of-RUNNING_PID

I am not sure how to get this set up correctly -- does anyone know if there are more detailed instructions I could follow?

I appreciate the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the answer from this post:
[Play change RUNNING_PID file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149196/play-change-running-pid-file-path)

Adding this to my application.conf file:

```
play.server.pidfile.path=/var/run/RUNNING_PID
```

worked like a charm!