# Unexpected JVM exit after first docker process is completed

Tags: docker, playframework, sbt, production-environment

I have an application running two services in a docker container. I'm running into a situation where the JVM unexpectedly exits after completing the first process (which is to build a jar from a play project) with the following message:

```
[info] Your package is ready in /app/.../project-0.1.0.zip
[success]
[Thread-2] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://sbt-web)] Starting coordinated shutdown from JVM shutdown hook
Archive:  /app/.../target/universal/project-0.1.0.zip
```

The second process (which is to extract the jar and run the application) begins with `Archive:  /app/.../target/universal/project-0.1.0.zip` but fails to extract the jar. The docker container does not exit.

Surprisingly, this issue is not seen in multiple runs after rebuilding and running the containers. Also, I had recently upgraded my sbt version from `0.13.11` to `1.1.1`. It was since then that I started facing this issue of `CoordinatedShutdown`. I am quite certain thus that this is not a docker issue.

I had also tried adding `akka.coordinated-shutdown.exit-jvm = off` and 
`akka.coordinated-shutdown.run-by-jvm-shutdown-hook = off` to my *application.conf* but `CoordinatedShutdown` still occurs. Any solutions?

Comment: If Java processes don't exit then a thread dump is handy for figuring out why.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! I figured out a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue was that the play application failed to start in its container because the RUNNING_PID file had not been deleted. Finally, managed to solve this by preventing Play from creating a PID with `-Dpidfile.path=/dev/null`.

Related issues: [Restarting Play application Docker container results in 'This application is already running' - RUNNING_PID is not deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351405/restarting-play-application-docker-container-results-in-this-application-is-alr/29244028#29244028)

References: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying#play-pid-configuration

Comment: I'm glad to hear you worked it out. Play should give a helpful error message when it sees a RUNNING_PID file already exists. Did a message show for you? Do you think we can improve the message?

Comment: Thanks, it sure did. I probably should have put it somewhere where it will be automatically cleared on restart, such as /var/run. But now i know. Is there a reason why this is not the default though?

Comment: The file is supposed to be cleared by Play when it's terminated. We add a JVM shutdown hook to make this happen, but perhaps the hook wasn't called for some reason. How are you terminating the Play instance?